# While ubuntu is suspended, my computer continues to run and use excessive battery power

Tags: 13.04, power-management, suspend, battery

I understand that suspend uses battery power to keep the information on the RAM, but I suspend ubuntu and later when I get my computer out of my bag, it is very hot. It is as if the hard drive and fans continue to run. Does anyone have a solution?? Thanks.

Comment: When you put it on suspend and close the lid, can you hear the hard drive and fan spinning?

Comment: it is not advisable to carry your laptop when suspended. Because in the bag it cuts out circulation of air need to cool your computer. Do you find your computer on after get it out of your bag?

Comment: I have the same problem. It happens mostly when my computer has been running for a while and is hot. I had it on 13.04 and 13.10.

Answer (score -1):

Because your notebooks cooling fan won't run after you suspend your system and your it's continuously running(only the RAM consumes power of course) so it will not be able get the heat out of box

Comment: No, suspend-to-ram implemented correctly uses very minimal amounts of power. For example, my notebook can be suspended for 14+ days without recharging. This really does not need any cooling fan to be running. I suspect the OP is running into a bug in where the kernel does not send the correct signal to the system's BIOS, so not all hardware is brought in the right ACPI power state.